# Align navigation buttons in Initializr template to bottom of navigation bar

Tags: css, html, initializr

I'm basing a website on the [Initializr](http://www.initializr.com/) bootstrap template. Instead of "Project name" in the upper left corner, I'm using an image. The navigation links are still align to the top of the page, but I would like them at the bottom of the black navigation bar:

[image: Initializr Bootstrap template navigation]

To reproduce the easiest is to download the Bootstrap template, and change the 'Project name' in the navbar to:

```
<a class="brand" href="#"><img src="apple-touch-icon-114x114-precomposed.png" /></a>
```

I cannot for the life of me get the links to align at the bottom of the navbar, unless by setting the `.navbar .nav` style in `bootstrap.css` (of .min.css) with a top margin of about 90px. This (pixel-based) solution feels like a wrong approach however.

I've tried playing around with `position: relative; bottom: 0` and `vertical-align: bottom` but to no avail. The amount of CSS in these templates doesn't help either (especially for a-developer-not-a-designer like me).

Can anyone get the links to neatly align to the bottom of the navigation bar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If fixed it myself by ditching Initializr (too powerful for what I needed) and using the following structure:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="navbar">
        <a href="index.html" class="logo">
            <img src="img/logo.png" />
        </a>
        <div class="nav">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="page1.html">Page 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html">Page 2</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div class="content">
        Content here
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following CSS:

```
#container { width: 1170px; margin: 0 auto; }
.navbar, .content { font-size: 1.6em; }
.navbar .logo { float: left; }
div.nav ul { list-style: none;padding: 0;}
div.nav ul li { display: inline;}
div.nav ul li a { display: block; background-image: url('../img/linksBackground.png'); background-position: 0 80px; background-repeat: no-repeat;
margin-top: 115px; float: left; padding: 11px 30px 9px 30px; text-decoration: none; color: #5dd2ff; }
div.nav ul li a:hover {color: #fff; background-position: 0 160px; background-color: #95e2ff;}
div.nav ul li.active a { color: #fff;font-weight: bold; background-position: left top; background-color: #5dd2ff;}

.clear { clear: both; }
```